# Exporting Nested Json Values to CSV using powershell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, parsing, psobject

I have been trying to loop through a list of .json config files to pull out 'name','entity_id','contact_info','sp_endpoint'. I have been trying to take the following code block, and dump it into a csv that lists each of the values in a column, and each row pertains to the file that value belongs to.

```
{
  "sfg_ping::qa::standard_sp_connections": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "entity_id": "test",
      "contact_info": "test@test.com",
      "sp_endpoint": "test",
      "sso_initialization_and_signature_policy": {
        "sign_assertion_or_response": "response",
        "sp_trust_model": "anchored",
        "signing_certificate_id": "test",
        "sp_initiated": {
          "require_signed_authn_requests": true,
          "primary_verification_certificate": "test"
        }
      }
```

I have been using this script to try and accomplish this, but it dumps empty values, and doesnt handle a bulk list of files.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\user\appdev\powershell-scripts\spConnections" |
ForEach-Object { 
    {(Select-String -Pattern 'name' )}
    {(Select-String -Pattern 'entity_id' )}
    {(Select-String -Pattern 'contact_info' )}
    {(Select-String -Pattern 'sp_endpoint' )}
    }| Export-Csv "C:\Users\user\appdev\powershell-scripts\export.csv"
```

The intended output would be something like this:

```
| filename | name | entityid |
|:---------|:----:| --------:|
| test     | test | test     |
```

Really lost here and just looking for some direction.

Comment: All these Json files have the same parent property `sfg_ping::qa::standard_sp_connections` ? Also, your code doesn't make much sense, what is `$_.disciplines.Count` and all those `discipline` properties and measurements you're showing in your code and how they related to the actual question ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Sorry! I just realized I pasted the wrong script ive been trying into my question. It is updated. I have also tried to use convertfrom-json, but I cant get past the parent property to dump the object properties that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can get the desired information from your Json files by following this logic, however it assumes that the Json files only have one parent Property, like `sfg_ping::qa::standard_sp_connections` but this would work with any Property Name as long as there is only one.

```
Get-ChildItem path\to\thejsonfolder -Filter *.json -PipelineVariable file | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_ -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).PSObject.Properties.Value | Select-Object @(
        @{ N = 'FileName'; E = { $file.Name }}, 'Name', 'entity_id', 'contact_info', 'sp_endpoint'
    )
} | Export-Csv path\to\myexport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The result I get for this using 2 different Json files:

```
FileName   name  entity_id contact_info   sp_endpoint
--------   ----  --------- ------------   -----------
test.json  test  test      test@test.com  test
test2.json test2 test2     test2@test.com test2
```

If they all had the same parent Property Name then:

```
(Get-Content $_ -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).PSObject.Properties.Value
```

Could be replaced by:

```
(Get-Content $_ -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).'sfg_ping::qa::standard_sp_connections'
```